# enable cURL on Azure, wordpress web apps

Tags: curl

I hosted my wordpress theme on Microsoft Azure web apps and I can't activate the theme because it required to enable cURL module to activate this theme.

So, how i can enable cURL on Microsoft Azure web apps ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it is Azure App Services (Windows). You can just upload the php_curl.dll to the webapp and reference it in the .user.ini file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime